# <md-autocomplete> is not initializing.

Tags: angularjs, md-autocomplete

this will be the function I tried when change the drop down

[This is my the code for autocomplete. I tried everything. I want to set the autocomplete to empty when I change the drop down]

Comment: Which Angular and Material version?

Comment: Try to be more precise. It is hard to understand what are you asking about. Maybe show some part of your code and try to arrange the question in other words.

Comment: There is no code visible, please share some code and/or create a plunker or codepen link.

Answer (score 0):

Added md-clear-button attribute with it.
`<md-autocomplete md-clear-button="true"</md-autocomplete>`